# Debugging a password complexity checker

Tags: c

I am trying to make a C program which can identify whether a password (not more than 10 digits) is strong or weak by checking is there are any uppercase letter. I have tried if...else statements. But there is a bug.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()

{

    char password[11];

    printf("What is your password (Must be 10 Digits)\n");
    scanf(" %s", password);

    if (isupper(password[0]) || isupper(password[1]) || isupper(password[2]) || isupper(password[3]) || isupper(password[4]) || isupper(password[5]) || isupper(password[6]) || isupper(password[7]) || isupper(password[8]) || isupper(password[9]) || isupper(password[10]) ) 
    {  printf("The password is strong\n");  }
    else { printf("It is a weak password\n"); }
```

Now if I type "word" it shows "The password is strong", but if I type a 10 digit password where all are small letters it shows "It is a weak password".

Comment: You probably want to use a loop to check each letter, and stop the loop when you reach the end of the string.

Comment: Presumably a password checker should return "strong" if the password is a mix of upper and lower case letters? If it is all upper-case then it is no stronger than an all lower-case string.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a for loop instead of that silly condition.

```
bool res = false;

for (int i = 0; password[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    if (isupper(password[i]) {
        res = true;
    }
}
if (res == true) {  
    printf("The password is strong\n");  
} else { 
    printf("It is a weak password\n"); 
}
```